# How to override the default Localization message of ABP exceptions?

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

I am developing an ABP application and I want to override the "InternalServerErrorMessage" with a custom message. My aim is to set this override to the entire application, so I don't need to write try-catch statements throughout the whole system.

The JSON file with all Exception messages can be found at: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.ExceptionHandling/Volo/Abp/ExceptionHandling/Localization/en.json

I tried to write some code at DomainSharedModule.cs and inside the Localization Folder (both are located at the Domain.Shared folder), but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder under the **Localization** folder in the `*.Domain.Shared` project and override the localization value by your need:

- **/Localizations/MyProject**

```json
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "InternalServerErrorMessage": "<your localization value>",
  }
}
```

Then, you can configure it in your `MyApplicationDomainSharedModule.cs` as below:

```json
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    //...        

    //add the following code
    options.Resources
        .Get<AbpExceptionHandlingResource>() //exception handling localization  resource
        .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/MyProject"); //your localization folder path

    options.DefaultResourceType = typeof(MyProjectNameResource);
});
```

Also, ensure you set the localization files as EmbeddedResource in your `*.Domain.Shared.csproj` file. Example: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core/src/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Shared/MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Domain.Shared.csproj#L22-L29

---

### Resources

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization
- https://community.abp.io/posts/how-to-override-localization-strings-of-depending-modules-ba1oy03l

Comment: I tried to apply this code, but the type "AbpExceptionHandlingResource" could not be found. It seems it is located inside "Volo.Abp.ExceptionHandling.Localization", but I cannot import it since "Localization" can't be found inside "Volo.Abp.ExceptionHandling" on my project.

Comment: @CândidoAlfredo great to hear that! Would you mind giving a vote up :) ?

Comment: I tried to vote up, but I need to have at least a 15 reputation on Stack Overflow. I encourage everyone who’s reading this comment to give a vote up.